# code doesn't work only in safari

Tags: javascript, safari

i am writing this code and it works in chrome and firefox but not in safari. i still don't really know a lot of javascript so i don't understand what the problem is. can anyone help? thank you.

```js
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

function myFunction() {
    if (document.getElementById("box").scrollTop > 80 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 80) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("box2")[0].className = "slideUp";
    }
}
```

```css
body{height:2000px;}

#copertina{height:800px; width:1000px; margin-left:0px; padding:0; float:left; margin-right:0px; margin-top:0px; background:url(img/_MG_6317.JPG); background-repeat:no-repeat; background-size:100%;}



#box{float:left; width:200px; height:200px; margin-top:50px; }

.box2{float:left; width:200px; height:200px; margin-top:50px; margin-left:100px; visibility:hidden}




.slideUp {animation-name: slideUp;-webkit-animation-name: slideUp;animation-duration: 1s;-webkit-animation-duration: 1s; visibility: visible;}

@keyframes slideUp {0% {opacity: 0;-webkit-transform: translateY(70%);} 100% {opacity: 1;-webkit-transform: translateY(0%);}}

@-webkit-keyframes slideUp {0% {opacity: 0;-webkit-transform: translateY(70%);} 100% {opacity: 1;-webkit-transform: translateY(0%);}}
```

```html
<body>

<div id="copertina"><p>Aldo Moro</p></div>

<div id="box">
<div class="box2">
<img src="img/IMG_2997.jpg" width="100%"></div>
</div>


<div id="box">
<div class="box2">
<img src="img/IMG_2983.jpg" width="100%"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: when you say "it doesn't work" ... are there errors? for example? like `document.getElementsByClassName(...)[0] is undefined`

Comment: you do realise the first time the scroll event occurs `document.getElementsByClassName("box2")[0].className = "slideUp";` will ensure that the second time the scroll event is fired, it will fail ... on **all browsers**

Comment: When I scroll in your snippet, I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'className' of undefined`, likely because once all elements with a className of "box2" are changed to "slideUp", `document.getElementsByClassName("box2")` returns an empty `NodeList`...